# Was the non-soldier Danny Pink killed originally supposed to have been a woman?

Tags: doctor-who

It's implied throughout Season 8 that Pink killed someone who wasn't a soldier.

In one of his earlier episodes, he freaks out when someone calls him a "lady-killer" (in the romantic sense). To me at least, this implied that his victim was a woman.

However, we later learn that he accidentally killed a young male, not a woman.

Was Pink originally intended to have accidentally killed an adult female? If not, why did he react so strongly when someone called him a lady-killer?

Comment: he probably simply triggered on the "killer" part...

Comment: “why did he react so strongly when someone called him a lady-killer?” — Yeah Danny! Get *over* it already!

Answer (score 4):

> he freaks out when someone calls him a "lady-killer" (in the romantic sense). To me at least, this implied that his victim was a woman.

It does not necessarily imply that the victim was female.

Imagine if someone jokingly called Danny a "serial killer". It would make him uncomfortable, even though he hasn't killed **multiple** people.

Similarly, being called a "lady killer" makes Danny uncomfortable because it makes him think "I am actually a killer". He's not freaking out over the gender of who he killed, he's freaking about *because he killed someone*.